# JavaScript truncate text by bytes length

Tags: javascript

I want to truncate a piece of utf8 encoded text to a given length in bytes. For example, if the text is

```
Hello , I like rice cakes ¯\_(ツ)_/¯
```

I would like to truncate that text to 10 bytes max.

I found the [truncate-utf8-bytes](https://www.npmjs.com/package/truncate-utf8-bytes) NPM module that does exactly what I need, unfortunately, the project I am working on doesn't use webpack or browerify so I cannot use those NPM modules as far as I'm aware

So I was wondering if there was a reliable way to truncate the text, or if there was a way for me to use the truncate-utf8-bytes module in the browser.

Thanks

Comment: Have you checked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1515884/using-javascript-to-truncate-text-to-a-certain-size-8-kb?

Comment: @Shinjo Yes I have, but I read the solutions there are deprecated. Also I need solutions that take into account of multi-byte characters and surrogate pairs.

Comment: Really? It's working good FWIW: https://jsfiddle.net/0xmcauqw/ Maybe you can add your desired output and "Also I need solutions that take into account of multi-byte characters and surrogate pairs." what is your input and expected output? Also what is your current progress, [mcve]

Comment: Did you not read the package's documentation? "*[A browser implementation](https://github.com/parshap/truncate-utf8-bytes/blob/master/browser.js) that doesn't use Buffer.byteLength is provided*" (using [this](https://github.com/parshap/utf8-byte-length/blob/master/browser.js) and [that](https://github.com/parshap/truncate-utf8-bytes/blob/master/lib/truncate.js)). If your project doesn't use a bundler, that means you have to bundle manually, but the code is still there.

Comment: how about something like [`this`](https://jsbin.com/dabumix/edit?js,console)

Comment: @Bergi I did, my interpretation of that was it doesn't use the Buffer library which is a node.js module, hence why it says browser, because browser don't have those modules.

Comment: Anyways, I have found an answer. Thanks @CodeManiac and Shinjo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this should work, assuming you know the encoding of the text:

```
let str = 'Hello , I like rice cakes ¯\_(ツ)_/¯';
let enc = new TextEncoder();
let dec = new TextDecoder('utf-8');
let uint8 = enc.encode(str)
let section = uint8.slice(0,11)
let result = dec.decode(section);
console.log('result', result);
```

Comment: I think this is exactly what I was looking for. I am already using TextDecoder to check the length in bytes, I just didn't know there was a TextEncoder. Thank you so much. Quick question, the uint8.slice(0, 11), does each array item represent one byte?

Comment: Yup, in that example uint8 is an array of 8-bit bytes (which is what you'd want for utf8). Note that slice will split through any characters that use multiple bytes. As I understand the TextDecoder makes it safe for rendering though but you might want to check that for your purposes.

Comment: Also note: TextEncoder only supports utf8 now (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TextEncoder) but there is a polyfill for other encodings.

Comment: This solution will not correctly truncate multi-byte characters - for example if you do `slice(0,8)` instead, you will get a corrupted character: `'Hello �'`

Answer (score 3):

Answer 1 works great but you might consider adding this to the end to avoid ending up with invalid characters that were truncated mid character:

```js
result.replace(/\uFFFD/g, '')
```